# What is Tahani's connection to the black market?

Tags: the-good-place

In season 3 episode 4 of *The Good Place*, at the 18:31 minute mark, Michael and Janet are saying that the experiment is over they are preparing a manifesto; however, in the background is a blackboard on which the names of all four humans are written: Chidi, Jason, Eleanor, and Tahani. Also on the blackboard are a list of the humans' pros and cons, followed by a green up-arrow if it is good or a red down-arrow if it is bad. For example under Chidi it says  "Helps others to be kind" with a green up-arrow. One of the items for Tahani says "**BLACK MARKET PURCHASES**," with a red down-arrow. This means that Tahani and maybe her parents and her sister where related to the black market, and purchase something illegal. So perhaps her attitude wasn't the only reason that Tahani went to the bad place, and her parents and sister may also have been in danger of going to the Bad Place.

Was Tahani's black market activity ever explained on the show?

Comment: I've edited this one for clarity, which hopefully forestalls the close votes. This is a good question.

Comment: Does it matter for the show what Tahani's connection is?

Comment: Yes, as the questioner states, a connection to the black market could mean that Tahani's attitude toward others--often presented as her main reason for going to the Bad Place--isn't really the only reason. Further, it could mean her family is also in jeopardy of going to the bad place.

Comment: Connection is probably a strong word.  She bought something on the black market ... yes that's (strictly) bad, but she was just a participant in a transaction to buy something.  When I buy something at a shop, beyond that transaction, I have no 'connection' to the shop.

Comment: Also why does it imply anything about her sister or parents?

Comment: A screenshot would be so welcomed on your question...